# Call modules from an other module

Tags: node.js

How can i call a module from a module?
Supposing i have two modules, mod_a and mod_b, in a directory called modules.

i would like to require mod_b from mod_a with `require('./mod_b.js')`, because they are located in the same directory.

Calling mod_a from a parent directory (with the main program) has the disadvantage that, it is called by `require('modules/mod_a.js');` and the internal mod_b isn't found.

Using `require(__dirname+'./mod_b.js')` in mod_a wasn't helpful either.

I m aware that this is a very basic question but i couldn't find a solution.

Fixed: everything is fine now, it was an typing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is more likely with the "*main program*" requiring `mod_a` than with `mod_a` requiring `mod_b`.

Relative `require()` paths are [expected to always start with a `./`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules) (or `../`):

> Without a leading `'/'` or `'./'` to indicate a file, the module is either a "core module" or is loaded from a `node_modules` folder.

So, the "*main program*" should instead be using:

```
require('./modules/mod_a.js');
```

Then, `mod_a` should be able to require `mod_b` without issue using:

```
require('./mod_b.js');
```

Comment: You are right! I misunderstood an error message and my conclusion was even worse. Reading slowly fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

`__dirname` will return something like `/home/user/modules` and you concatenate it with `./mod_b.js` and get `/home/user/modules./mod_b.js`, but you expect `/home/user/modules/mod_b.js`

solutions:

1. remove the beginning `.`
2. or add an `/` at the beginning
3. or use [path.join](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2)